# VSTO Word AddIn : Capture Paste operation by Ctrl+V

Tags: c#, vsto

I am working on a VSTO Word AddIn project and I copy some paragraph from an external source (some other word doc) and want to paste it by using Ctrl + V in word addin.

After copying some texts and to paste the copied data into the word document, it should paste the copied data + I want to add some more custom functionalities like keeping the same format of the destination word doc. how to do that ?

Comment: Is it possible to use ```System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard``` class? 
https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/dotnet/api/system.windows.clipboard?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

Answer (score 0):

To control the keyboard shortcuts for pasting some data into your document you can set up a keyboard hook using the `SetWindowsHookEx` Windows API function. For example:

```
        private const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
        private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;

        private static IntPtr hookId = IntPtr.Zero;
        private delegate IntPtr HookProcedure(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
       

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, HookProcedure lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            hookId = SetHook(HookCallback);
        }

        private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(hookId);
        }

        private static IntPtr SetHook(HookProcedure procedure)
        {
            using (Process process = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
            using (ProcessModule module = process.MainModule)
                return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, procedure, GetModuleHandle(module.ModuleName), 0);
        }

        private IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            try
            {
                if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN)
                {
                    int pointerCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
                    string pressedKey = ((Keys)pointerCode).ToString();

                    //Do some sort of processing on key press
                    var thread = new Thread(() =>
                    {
                        

                        if (Control.ModifierKeys != 0 && pointerCode == 48 && Keys.Shift != 0)
                        {
                            //    
                            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Selection currentSelection = Application.Selection;
                            if (currentSelection.Type == Word.WdSelectionType.wdSelectionIP)
                            {

                                currentSelection.TypeBackspace();
                                currentSelection.TypeText("()");
                                currentSelection.MoveLeft(1);

                                pointerCode = 0;
                            }
                            else
                                if (currentSelection.Type == Word.WdSelectionType.wdSelectionNormal)
                            {
                                currentSelection.TypeBackspace();
                                currentSelection.MoveLeft(1);
                                currentSelection.TypeText("()");
                                pointerCode = 0;

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // Do nothing.
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {

                        }

                    });
                    thread.Start();
                }
                
            }
            catch
            {

            }

            return CallNextHookEx(hookId, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        }
```

To handle ribbon controls (including context menus) you can repurpose built-in controls. See [Temporarily Repurpose Commands on the Office Fluent Ribbon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/bb462633(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can patch the [GetClipboardData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getclipboarddata) Windows API function using [Detours](https://github.com/citronneur/detours.net) and run any code you want in your new function.

Works for both Ctrl+V and paste from a popup menu.